# INA125 problems

Tags: instrumentation-amplifier, wheatstone-bridge

I'm trying to measure a bridge sensor using an INA125 connected to my Arduino and Adafruit ads1115, but the output seems stuck on 5.88V (the power supply is 12V singl supply). Its connected as in the diagram below. Even with a completely balanced bridge (i.e no significant voltage difference to amplify) and gain disconnected (i.e. g=x4) it still outputs 5.88V at the output pins 10 and 11 (connected together as per diagram below). Any help much appreciated! [image: schematic]

[image: Actual circuit]

Comment: You should provide the **schematic** of your actual circuit...the photo doesn't help at all. Have you tried replacing the amplifier? Have you checked the voltages at all of its pins? If so, tell us what they are.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson The only connection from the INA125 besides the 12V power supply is to the 1st analogue input (A0) of the ADS1115. The voltages are from pin1 to 16 of the INA are: 12V, 12V, GND, 2.5V (as pin 4 is connected to pin 14, the 2.5V ref pin), 2.5V (pin 5 connected to pin 4), 0.3V, 1.27V, 1.27V, 3.3V, 10.4V, 10.4, GND, 1.23, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5

Comment: I have disconnected the arduino from the above photo, which was only connected to the ADS1115, and now pins 10 and 11 seem to have gone to 10.4V? Besides this the INA is acting exactly as I expected

Comment: Well, you can't connect a voltage greater than the Arduino's supply voltage to one of its analog input pins.  You shouldn't even try connecting 5.88V to the Arduino. Have you tried replacing the amplifier itself...it may be faulty.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson I wasn't going to - I need to get the amp working first - do you know have an idea why its giving that voltage out?

Comment: You said you "disconnected the Arduino" and then pins 10 and 11 "have gone to 10.4V". What else could that mean? At this point we are both guessing. Build another circuit to rule out wiring errors, replace the amplifier to rule out a faulty chip.

Comment: The arduino was only connected to the ADS1115 by i2c. In the photo the vout at pins 10 and 11 was 5.88. I disconnected the Arduino, leaving the connections direct to the amp exactly the same, connect the power and now the same vout is at 10.4? Any idea why this could be?